Prove the assignment A → A/T(A) (T(A) is the torsion subgroup of A) is a functor
Prove the assignment A → A/T(A) (T(A) is the torsion subgroup of A) is a functor between the Ab category of abelian groups and the TFAB category of torsion-free abelian groups.
I know I have to prove that F preserves composition and identity. But I don't know how to prove it since I'm not familiar with torsion groups

You first have to define what the functor does on morphisms. That is, you're given a homomorphism $A\rightarrow B$. Can you construct a homomorphism $A/T(A)\rightarrow B/T(B)$ from this?

First prove that $F(A)$ is torsion free. For $[x] =x + T(A) \in F(A)$, $n>0$ if $n[x] = [0]$, then $nx \in T(A)$, so there exists $m>0$ such that $m(nx)= 0$, i.e. $(mn)x=0$ so $x \in T(A)$ hence $[x] = [0]$. So all non zero elements of $F(A)$ are torsion free.

Now, define $F(f)$ for any morphism $f$:
For a morphism $f: A \to B$, study the morphism $\pi_B \circ f: A \to F(B)$.
Since $f(T(A)) \subset T(B)$ as for all $x \in A, \, nf(x) =f(nx)$, so $nx=0 \implies nf(x) = 0$.
By the universal property of the quotient map $\pi_A:A \to F(A)$, since $\pi_B \circ f \circ \imath_A = 0$ (where $\imath_A: T(A) \to A$ is the inclusion morphism, there is an unique morphism $\bar{f}: F(A) \to F(B)$ such that $\pi_B \circ f = \bar{f} \circ \pi_A$.
We thus define $F(f) = \bar{f}$.

Now we only need to prove the stability by composition:
Take $f:A\to B$ and $g:B \to C$. Notice that
$$\bar{g} \circ \bar{f} \circ \pi_A = \bar{g} \circ \pi_B \circ f = \pi_C \circ g \circ f = \overline{(g \circ f)} \circ \pi_A$$
This is given by the three equalities: $\pi_B \circ f = \bar{f} \circ \pi_A$, $\quad \pi_C \circ g = \bar{g} \circ \pi_B$ and $\pi_C \circ (g\circ f) = \overline{(g\circ f)} \circ \pi_A$
But the unicity given by the universal property gives us
$$F(g) \circ F(f) = \bar{g} \circ \bar{f} = \overline{(g \circ f)} = F(g\circ f)$$

You can now conclude that $F$ is a functor from the category of Abelian groups to the full subcategory of torsion-free abelian groups.
A small exercise: show that $F$ has a right adjoint.

 The right adjoint is the inclusion functor $\mathrm{TFAb} \to \mathrm{Ab}$.


Thank you for your help

@CarmenGardón If you have got everything you seeked, please accept the question and do not hesitate to vote it up

@ julio_es_sui_glace I do not understand why πB∘f∘πA=0, because this composition in not well defined.If you could help me I will appreciate it!

@CarmenGardón Indeed you are right, I meant $\imath_{T(A)}$ the inclusion of the subgroup $T(A)$ into $A$. Let me correct it

Thank you very much!!! I really appreciate your help
